# 'Unused Arguments' error in mediate function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a mediation analysis in R using the mediation package, but I keep getting an error of the type:

Error in mediate(model.m, model.y, sims = 1000, boot = TRUE, treat = "Treat",  : 
  unused arguments (sims = 1000, boot = TRUE, treat = "Treat", mediator = "Med")

The code I'm running is:

```
    model.y <- lm(Perf~Treat*InteractionVar + Med, s)
    model.m <- lm(Med~Treat, s)
    out.1 <- mediate(model.m, model.y, sims = 1000, boot = TRUE, treat="Treat", mediator = "Med")
```

I get the same error even if I remove the InteractionVar from the formula too. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you accidentally create your own `mediate()` function that shadows the package function? What does `environment(mediate)` return? What if you tried `mediation::mediate(...)` just to make sure?

Comment: can you create a small dataset for us to work with?

Comment: @MrFlick amazing - thank you! Mediate() was being called from the psych package and not the mediation package. Using mediation::mediate(...) solved it!